# Not sure how to continue after declaring variables. Very basic java

Tags: java, variables, printf

Just started programming in highschool. Im having trouble writing this program.

The details are as follows :
Write a short program that requests your height in feet and inches and your weight in pounds. then the program will display your bmi. To calculate the bmi first convert your height to inches and then convert to meters by multiplying by 2.54x10^-2. Then convert weight in pounds into kilograms by dividing by 2.2. Then compute bmi by dividing mass in kg by height in meters^2.

Would i be using double or int for declaring anything in this program? I still havent gotten the hang of what scenarios use what. And ive attempted to think ahead and see if i start from there but im not sure how my printf statement would look.

//Sample output

Enter your height: 
feet: 5 
inches: 8 
What is your weight? (in pounds): 139

printf statement: A 5 foot by 8 inch adult of 139.0 pounds has a BMI of 21.2

I got stuck after declaring variables and not sure how else to continue. I can get the system.out.print statements for the height and weight but not sure how to get the equations set up or the final printf statement. An explanation to why a segment of code was used would be helpful but if not im sure i can figure it out on my own. Thanks for helping!

Note: Ive tried reddit but the one answer i got was vague and just kept saying google, and also tried yahoo answers but they were talking about terms i havent learned. Ive only been coding for 2 weeks so if possible please dont make the explanation too alien. If thats not avoidable ill just google the definitions haha. Anyways thanks again

Comment: Post the code you wrote.

Comment: Check this out http://www.hubberspot.com/2012/06/how-to-calculate-bmi-of-body-in-java.html

Comment: Hi, the forum would help you in resolving the issue/technical problems but not help you in writing code for you. Please post the code you have written for us to help. If you are new to Java, I suggest you to read HeadFirst Java edition.

Answer (score 2):

This truly is very simple. Here's my code for your specifications:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMICalculator
{

    public static final double TO_KILO = 0.453592;
    public static final double TO_METERS = 0.0254;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Define some starting variables and Scanner object
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int heightFeet, heightInches, weight;

        //Get the user input for height and weight
        System.out.println("Enter your height...");
        System.out.print("Feet: ");
        heightFeet = s.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Inches: ");
        heightInches = s.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Weight (lbs): ");
        weight = s.nextInt();

        //Do calculations and conversions
        int inInches = (heightFeet * 12) + heightInches;
        double heightInMeters = inInches * TO_METERS;
        double weightInKilo = weight * TO_KILO;

        //Get BMI
        double bmi = weightInKilo / (heightInMeters * heightInMeters);

        System.out.printf("A %d foot by %d inch adult of %dlbs. has a BMI of %.2f.\n", heightFeet, heightInches, weight, bmi);

        s.close();
    }

}
```

In the future, I suggest doing a bit more research and learning how to program in the desired language prior to posting a question, or you won't learn anything!

Answer (score 2):

You're essentially asking how to go about solving a programming problem. Here are some steps and directions that hopefully will help you out.

- Identify what you need to solve
- Identify inputs and outputs
- Explicitly consider bad inputs and how you should handle those
- Identify an algorithm to solve your problem at a high level

In this case it's basically:
- ask for input
- read input
- do computation
- print output

- Break down the steps of the algorithm into further steps, at a finer and finer granularity.
- For each section of the algorithm, one at a time, translate that section into code and make sure that section of code works. Repeat this for each section of code
- Now glue each section together until everything all works together
- Verify and test, and now go back and polish your code so it reads well (it's like editing an English paper, first draft is not done).

For example, one way to start might be with the print output step. Start by example printing out hardcoded values:
System.out.println("A 5 foot by 8 inch adult of 139.0 pounds has a BMI of 21.2")

Then as a next step replace the numbers with variables. Then replace the BMI with a computation. Repeat this type of process until your algorithm is completely translated into code. One trick is do it one small section at a time (so if anything is ever complicated, keep breaking it down until it is trivially simple to solve).

I would suggest researching these topics to help you get a foundation (do a lot of skimming familiarization of each, and try then to do some deep reading of each in rough order):
- algorithm, history and definition
- java variable types, overview of what they are the values they store
- operators and boolean logic (http://computer.howstuffworks.com/boolean.htm)